# Does IN_MOVE_TO directly follow a IN_MOVE_FROM in inotify?

Tags: unix, inotify

When a file is moved, inotify will issue `IM_MOVE_FROM`, `IN_MOVE_TO` or both. There is a cookie field in the event whose value allows us to determine the linked events.

What is not specified is the order of linked `MOVE` events and whether the `MOVE_TO` always directly follows the linked `MOVE_FROM` (if both are issued).

May there be other events between them ?

If yes, may there be multiple `MOVE` event pairs mixed up?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an authoritative answer to your exact question, but wanted to share what we do in the [watchman code](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/master/watcher/inotify.cpp) which is heavily battle-tested on a large fleet of Linux machines with a large volume of files and a high rate of change.

We defensively make the following assumptions:

1. MOVE_FROM comes before MOVE_TO
2. We may not get a MOVE_FROM
3. We may not get a MOVE_TO

Because we're a bit pessimistic and the wording in the inotify docs is ambiguous, we record the cookie -> move information in a map so that we don't rely on MOVE_TO coming directly after the MOVE_FROM.  It's also a little more complicated because the MOVE_FROM may be the last data that fit in your read buffer on one read and the MOVE_TO may be the first data of a subsequent read.

We purge the map whenever we have consumed all available data from the inotify stream (eg: a non-blocking read returns 0 bytes).  Anything in that map was in the (3.) category above and won't show up in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was helpful. It is not easy but the way you handle it seams to cover all cases. When you have processed events and the map is not empty, do you do a none blocking read to check if there is some more events ? How do you determine if the MOVE_TO is absent ? In case of very intensive inotify activity (created/deleted 10000 files) there is a risk that you have to wait long until a read 0 event occurs. Is there a timeout ? It would be simpler if we could assume that the MOVE_TO immediately follows the MOVE_FROM if present (eventually in the next read event batch).

Comment: I linked to the code so you can see what we do for yourself.  Watchman's model is to not directly track renames, so we ideally would just ignore this.  However, we must do some basic tracking to understand when inotify has unilaterally changed the watch descriptor -> name mapping.